# erro ao comparar sha1 em php

Tags: php, sha1

Estou fazendo um sistema de login mas ao comparar a senha que o usuário digitou com a que está no banco de dados da erro. Quando o usuário se cadastra no sistema aplica dois `sha1` tipo : `sha1(sha1($_POST['senha']));`

Mas quando eu vou comparar da algum erro, pois não é o mesmo código salvo, eu não sei se é algo no código, segue ai o código, desde já agradeço..

```
  if(isset($_POST['email']) && strlen($_POST['email']) > 0){

if(!isset($_SESSION))
  session_start();

   $link = DBConnect();
   $_SESSION['email'] = $link->escape_string($_POST['email']);
   $_SESSION['senha'] = sha1(sha1($_POST['senha']));


$UserCheck = DBRead( 'usuarios', "WHERE email = '". $_POST['email']."'", 'id,email,senha');  
var_dump($UserCheck);
$id = (string)$UserCheck[0]['id'];
$email = (string)$UserCheck[0]['email'];
$senha = (string)$UserCheck[0]['senha'];
var_dump($id.'</br></br>'.$email.'</br>'.$senha);
$senhasession = sha1(sha1($_SESSION['senha']));
var_dump($senhasession);
  if ($email)
    if($senha == $senhasession){
      $_SESSION['usuario'] = $id;
      //echo "<script>location.href='admin.php'</script>";
      echo $id;
    }
    else{
      //echo "<script>alert('Senha incorreta!');</script>";
    }

  else{
    echo "<script>alert('Email incorreto!');</script>";
  }
```

}

Comment: deu algum erro no editor no forum pq eu digitei o if corretamente

Comment: Qual o sentido de usar o sha1 2x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nesse techo

```
$senhasession = sha1(sha1($_SESSION['senha']));
```

modifique para

```
$senhasession = $_SESSION['senha'];
```

O motivo é que numa linha anterior já está aplicando o "duplo sha1"

```
$_SESSION['senha'] = sha1(sha1($_POST['senha']));
```

Comment: Deu certo! Obrigado parceiro!